# Ensuring proper handling of response in rails action called by a javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The following javascript snippet submits data to a Rails controller action

```
Rails.ajax({
  url: "section_update",
  type: "post",
  data: formData
});
```

However, the log points out that

```
Started POST "/articles/section_update" for 176.200.200.92 at 2020-07-27 18:07:20 +0200
Processing by ArticlesController#section_update as */*
```

how can the javascript be modified so that the action gets handled as JS - or force the action to only respond via the `js.erb` convention ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly add a `respond_to` block in your controller.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { redirect_to some_path} #If you need to redirect
  format.js                          #If you want to render a js.erb view matching the action.
end
```

The 'Rails Way' would be to remove this snippet of JS code and just add `remote: true` to the link or form that's handling the formData. This tells Rails to submit the request as JS automagically.